# Tensor slicing: tensorflow vs pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch, slice

I was testing this simple slicing operation in TF and PyTorch which should match in both

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import torch
tf_x = tf.random.uniform((4, 64, 64, 3))

pt_x = torch.Tensor(tf_x.numpy())
pt_x = pt_x.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
# slicing operation
print(np.any(pt_x[:, :, 1:].permute(0, 2, 3, 1).numpy() - tf_x[:, 1:].numpy())) 
# > False

pt_x = torch.Tensor(tf_x.numpy())
b, h, w, c = pt_x.shape
pt_x = pt_x.reshape((b, c, h, w))
print(np.any(pt_x.view(b, h, w, c).numpy() - tf_x.numpy())) # False
print(np.any(pt_x[:, :, 1:].reshape(4, 63, 64, 3).numpy() - tf_x[:, 1:].numpy())) 
# > True
```

In the last line lies the problem. Both PyTorch and TF should lead to the same value but they don't. Is this discrepancy caused when I try to reshape the tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand, you have `pt_x` equal to `tf_x`, use [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to verify:

```
>>> np.isclose(pt_x.view(b, h, w, c).numpy(), tf_x.numpy()).all()
True
```

On the other hand, you are slicing both tensors differently: `pt_x[:, :, 1:]` removes the first element along `axis=2`, while `tf_x[:, 1:]` removed the first element along `axis=1`. Therefore you end up with two distinct elements with overlapping values, like `tf_x[:, 1:][0,-1,-1,-1]` and `pt_x[0,-1,-1,-1]`.

Also keep in mind tensor layouts are different in Tensorflow and PyTorch, while the former uses channel last layout, the latter does channel first. The operation needed between those two is a permutation (not a reshape).

Comment: Thanks. Permute was working fine. I am now trying to understand how 'reshape' works under the hood. Also, I couldn't understand this part of your answer: 'Therefore you end up with two distinct elements with overlapping values, like tf_x[:, 1:][0,-1,-1,-1] and pt_x[0,-1,-1,-1]'. If possible can you post a link that explains this concept?